# Batching Operations in Boltdb

Tags: go, embedded-database, batching, boltdb

Currently using db.Update() to  update the key-value in boltdb.

```
err := db.Update(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {

    b, err := tx.CreateBucket([]byte("widgets"))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := b.Put([]byte("foo"), []byte("bar")); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
})
```

How to use db.Batch() operations using go routines?

Answer (score 2):

Just call db.Batch() from your goroutines. Batch() was created to be used this way. There is an example in [documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/boltdb/bolt#DB.Batch).

Comment: Thanks! I saw that,it is using a server.I need a simpler example as I am a beginner.